# How do i overwrite email/order/shipment/track.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, shipment-tracking

There is a core file named

> email/order/shipment/track.phtml

in the theme base default.

Now i have added a PHTML file to my own theme called ABC/Default and in the folder

> email/order/shipment/track.phtml

In the transactional email i have this code:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

But it still picks the core phtml instead of the custom one.

How do i see my custom one in the transactional emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the below file:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/shipment/track.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/email/order/shipment/track.phtml

No need to do anything else. Flush the cache and change whatever you want to your theme's track.phtml

Don't forget to flush the cache.

Comment: like i said in the question, i did this and flushed the cache, but did not work at all.

Comment: Did you try by editing base file, if it works? As may be any extension override this file.

Comment: I did edit the base file and that worked. i really dont want to make an extention to overwrite one file.

Comment: I am not asking to override it with new module. I am asking that it may be overridden. But you said its not overriden as it works when you edit the core. Then something wrong with file location you are adding.

Comment: data/web/public/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/shipment/track.phtml <- this is the core file i'd like to edit. I have added the custom file in this path -> data/web/public/app/design/frontend/abc/default/template/email/order/shipment/track.phtml

Comment: And what is your theme path?

Comment: See edit of prev comment

Comment: Looks ok. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

1. The design was wrongly configured in the backend.
2. The design theme was configured as default and not as my custom theme.